# easy way to calculate the off-diagonal element of a product of complicated matrices composed of sin and cosine

Tags: matrices, trigonometry

Let $A_i(x)$ be a $2 \times 2$ complex (unitary) matrix:
\begin{equation}
A_i(x) = e^{-iH(x)y_i} \text{ where  } H(x) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ x & -1 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

More explicitly, by using infinite series of an exponential, we get:
\begin{equation}
A_i(x) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta_i - \frac{i \sin \theta_i}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} & - \frac{i x \sin \theta_i}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \\ -\frac{i x \sin \theta_i}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} & \cos \theta_i + \frac{i \sin \theta_i}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \end{pmatrix}, 
\end{equation} where $\theta_i = y_i\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$. Consider a product of these matrices where the sign of $x$ alternative between $+$ and $-$:
\begin{equation}
U = A_1(x) A_2(-x) \cdots A_{k-1}(x) A_k(-x) \text{ where } k \text{ is even}
\end{equation} with the following constraint: $ (\sum_{i=1}^k y_i)\sqrt{x^2 + 1} < 1$. For any finite number of $k$, and $\{y_i\}$ and $x$ that satisfy the constraint, I want to prove that the real part of the upper off-diagonal matrix element of $U$, i.e. $\Re[U_{12}]$, is always positive.

When $k= 2$ and $k=4$, by directly calculating $U$, it is easy to show the statement holds. But as $k$ gets bigger, it's hard to explicitly calculate the matrix. I've tried to solve by using induction (as well as several other techniques), but I failed. Any intuition on how to approach this problem would be much appreciated. (BTW, I ran Python codes and couldn't find a counter-example yet).

Comment: It would be great if you could share more details on how $A_i$ was obtained, and what the condition on $\sum y_i$ mean. It might shed some light on the properties of $A_i$.

Comment: @Tulip Indeed, I added more fundamental form of $A_i$.

Comment: You launch into a description of $A_i$ but never circle back to explain what the $y_i$ values are.  Are they arbitrary real numbers, apart from meeting the single inequality bound on their sum?

Comment: @hardmath yes, that's correct. They (as well as $x$) are arbitrary real values that satisfy the constraint.

Comment: It seems you are using $i$ both as an index and as the conventional imaginary unit.  Maybe use $k$ as the index and $n$ as the upper end of the index range?

Answer (score 0):

If you diagonalize $-iH(x)$ for x not 0 (it is diagonal already if $x =0$) in the form $M(x)D(x)M(x)^{-1}$ you get

$D = \begin{pmatrix}
i\omega & 0\\ 
 0 & -i\omega
\end{pmatrix}=-i\omega\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\ 
 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}   $ where $\omega=(1+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $M = \begin{pmatrix}
x & x\\ 
 -1-\omega & -1+\omega
\end{pmatrix} $

Then $A_{k}(x)=M(x)e^{Dy_k}M(x)^{-1}$

It follows that $D(-x)=D(x)$ and that $M(-x)=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\ 
 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} M(x)$

I dob't know how much that might help, if at all! I would have put this in a comment but it is a bit fiddly.